# C# - How to know how many bytes are left in TcpClient after perform SslStream.Read

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl, client-server, tcpclient

I'm doing a client-server app, the server will check when there is data available (TcpClient.Available > 0) to read, but when it runs SslStream.Read, even though I know how many bytes I need to read, it still sets the TcpClient.Available back to 0 and leave the already read bytes ... unread by my code because the condition (TcpClient.Available > 0) would be false so that the server won't do anything with the additional bytes until the client sends more bytes, which is not wanted, the server should process all the bytes sent by the client as soon as possible.
Here is some code:

```
static void main()
{
    TcpClient tcpClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    SslStream s = new SslStream(tcpClient.GetStream(), false);
    //authenticate etc ...
    while (true)
    {
        if (tcpClient.Available > 0) // now this condition is false until
                                     // the client send more bytes
                                     // which is not wanted
            work(tcpClient);
    }
}
    
static void work(TcpClient c)
{
    //client sent 50 bytes
    byte[] data = new byte[10];
    s.Read(data, 0, 10); // I know this is not guaranteed to read 10 bytes 
    //so I have a while loop to read until it receives all the byes, this line is just for example
    
    // do something with the 10 bytes I read, back to the while loop
 }
```

my "work" actually create a new thread to do the work and lock that client until the work is done so that that  client  will not call work until the work is done

Since I know how many bytes are needed for a "work" to run I only read that number of bytes and unlock the client so that the client can "work" again

And of course there are other clients that need to work too, here I just show one to demonstrate the problem

Comment: Read until `Read` reads 0 bytes.

Comment: The SSL layer will not return *any* plaintext until it has a received a complete SSL record and verified its integrity.

Comment: What you are doing here, checking Available in a loop, is a very bad thing to do. It is called polling. It either eats CPU resources or results in terrible response times. Trying to balance these two concerns is a meaningless exercise. @HaroldMorgan explains what you should do instead.

Comment: @Llama _"Read until Read reads 0 bytes"_, not true. If you read 0 bytes, means the socket is closed.

Comment: @Jeroen depending on the stream, there is no way to know if the next call to `Read` will return 0, so you can't stop reading _before_ it returns 0 if you wish to be sure you read everything. You therefore have to read _until_ it returns 0, indicating the stream is closed as you said.

Comment: @Llama The 'confusion' is, that the question is _"How to know how many bytes are left in TcpClient after perform SslStream.Read"_ and your answer was _"Read until Read reads 0 bytes"_. That probably put me on the wrong foot. Because reading 0 bytes means disconnection. We agree on: There is no way to get the available bytes left. Because it's streaming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally don't know how many bytes is *left* to read from stream.

But you can just read from the stream "while it's reading" because [SslStream.Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream.read?view=net-6.0) returns the amount of bytes read!

So your code transforms into simple

```
while (s.Read(data, 0, 10) > 0)
{
    // do something with the bytes you've read
}
```

It's the way people work with streams in general - reading them by chunks while it's reading.

You can see it (And much more! You should definetely check it out) in the examples from the documentation I've linked earlier

Comment: Your example is not complete. Because you need the result of the `s.Read(..)` to know how many bytes you actually received.

Comment: You're right, and example from documentation that I've linked does a much better job explaining whole process, I've just tried to express general idea of "how you should work with stream" and provided a path for studying the question further